# firebase deploy - Unexpected Error 502 error and 'Cannot Create Property 'error' on String'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy an web-app to firebase hosting that has previously worked. The only recent changes I have made to the app are adding a new cloud function and rewrite rule to the firebase.json file. The app successfully deploys right past the "all functions have deployed successfully" step then gives me the **'unexpected error'** message. I have tried removing the most recent additions but the error is still occurring. I have also tried updating to the latest version of Node and rolling back to previous versions to no avail. The app and functions and rewrites all work without error using **'firebase serve'**

The two errors that I can see are a 502 error and a **'cannot create property 'error' on string'**, but I am at a loss as to what is causing these errors, since they only appear to happen during a deploy. I was also unable to find a working solution online.

I've attached my firebase-debug.log for the latest deploy as well as my firebase.json file with the rewrite rules I've written.

I am running Windows 10 64-bit, and Node v6.14.1

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

firebase.json

```
"database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites" : [ {
        "source": "/inventory/**", "function": "loadItemPage"
      }, {
        "source": "/authenticate", "function": "loadAuthPage"
      }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

firebase-debug.log (starting right before the error)

```
[info] +  functions: all functions deployed successfully!
[debug] [2018-04-30T18:17:17.630Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/projects/oldstrum-9ac64/releases { database: { rulesString: '{\r\n  "rules": {\r\n    ".read": "auth != null",\r\n    ".write": "auth != null"\r\n  }\r\n}' },
  storage: { rules: [ [Object] ] },
  hosting: 
   { public: 'public',
     rewrites: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     ignore: [ 'firebase.json', '**/.*', '**/node_modules/**' ],
     version: '-LBMlAb1hoCrTbJ8yJUC',
     prefix: '-LBMlAb1hoCrTbJ8yJUC/',
     manifest: [] } } 
 Mon Apr 30 2018 11:17:17 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
[debug] [2018-04-30T18:17:25.114Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 502
[debug] [2018-04-30T18:17:25.114Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

[debug] [2018-04-30T18:17:25.115Z] TypeError: Cannot create property 'error' on string '<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
'
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Jesse Lee Kuras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:11:16)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Jesse Lee Kuras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\api.js:39:25)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Jesse Lee Kuras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jesse Lee Kuras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jesse Lee Kuras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue. I had `firebase-tool` version 3.12.0 installed. When I updated to 3.18.4, it worked.